# equivalence of equations

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica

A reviewer of a paper I submitted to a scientific journal insists that my function

```
f1[b_, c_, t_] := 1 - E^((c - t)/b)/2
```

is "mathematically equivalent" to the function

```
f2[b0_, b1_, t_] := 1 - b0 E^(-b1 t)
```

He insists

> While the models might appear(superficially) to be different, the  f1
>   model is merely a re-parameterisation of the f2 model, and this can be
>   seen easily using highschool mathematics.

I survived High School, but I don't see the equivalence, and FullSimplify does not yield the same results.  Perhaps I am misunderstanding FullSimplify.  Is there a way to authoritatively refute or confirm the assertion of the reviewer?

Comment: Consider http://math.stackexchange.com/ for math related questions as this.

Answer (score 3):

If c and b are constant, you can factor them out relatively easily given the property of the power operator:

```
e^(A + B) = e^A x e^B...
```

so

```
e^((c - t)/b) = e^(c/b - t/b) = e^(c/b) x  e^(-t/b) = b0 x e^(-t/b)
```

The latter expression is commonly used to simplify linear differential equation.